# getting a subview's WINDOW coordinates issue with convertRect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

from main viewController's **ViewDidAppear**

```
UIView* parent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
UIView* child1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 60, 60)];
UIView* child2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];

[parent setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[child1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[child2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

[child1 addSubview:child2];
[parent addSubview:child1];
[self.view addSubview:parent];

NSLog(@"Absolute coordinates of child2: %@",NSStringFromCGRect([child2 convertRect:child2.frame toView:nil] ));
```

**abs point of child2: {{150, 170}, {20, 20}}**

I was expecting the origins to be (140,140, 20,20).

Why the extra 10 for the `X` and 30 for the `Y`?

Answer (score 10):

What you need to call is:

`[child2.superview convertRect:child2.frame toView:nil]`

**NOT**

`[child2 convertRect:child2.frame toView:nil]`

ie. you need to call `convertRect:` on the view that contains the frame you are converting.

Then you'll probably find X == 140 and Y == 160, with the extra 20 Y being the **status bar** given that `self.view` lives within the `UIWindow` beneath it.

Comment: May I ask why call the superview and not the view itself?

Comment: @Ted As the docs say about `- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view` - "Converts a rectangle from the receiver’s coordinate system to that of another view." And child2.frame is defined in the coord system of it's parent view.